# Calling a WCF service with certificate from a client application without having the contract interface

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl-certificate, wcf-binding, wcf-client

My particular problem is something like this:

- I am able to invoke WCF service dynamically, but i need to provide certificate.
- We don't want to use app.config.
- Major issue is that WCF service is a 3rd party url.
- Actually, i am getting an exception while invoke instance that certificate is not provided.
- My code is something like this:

  ```
      try
      {
          // Define the metadata address, contract name, operation name, 
          // and parameters. 
          // You can choose between MEX endpoint and HTTP GET by 
          // changing the address and enum value.
          Uri mexAddress = new Uri("http://Some3rdPartyURL.svc?wsdl");//Some 3rd party url
          // For MEX endpoints use a MEX address and a 
          // mexMode of .MetadataExchange


          MetadataExchangeClientMode mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;

          string contractName = "IService";//"";//3rd party service name
          string operationName = "SendMethod";//3rd party method name
          object[] args = new object[] { "", "", "0" };//3rd party required parameters
          //object[] operationParameters = new object[] { /*1, 2*/args };

          // Get the metadata file from the service.
          MetadataExchangeClient mexClient =
          new MetadataExchangeClient(mexAddress, mexMode);
          mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
          MetadataSet metaSet = mexClient.GetMetadata();

          // Import all contracts and endpoints
          WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaSet);

          Collection<ContractDescription> contracts =
                 importer.ImportAllContracts();
          ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();

          // Generate type information for each contract
          ServiceContractGenerator generator = new ServiceContractGenerator();

          var endpointsForContracts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();

          foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
          {
              generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
              // Keep a list of each contract's endpoints
              endpointsForContracts[contract.Name] = allEndpoints.Where(
                se => se.Contract.Name == contract.Name).ToList();
          }

          if (generator.Errors.Count != 0)
              throw new Exception("There were errors during code compilation.");

          // Generate a code file for the contracts 
          CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
          options.BracingStyle = "C";
          CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

          // Compile the code file to an in-memory assembly
          // Don't forget to add all WCF-related assemblies as references
          CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(
               new string[] { 
                   "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll", 
                  "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"});
          compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

          CompilerResults results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(
              compilerParameters, generator.TargetCompileUnit);

          if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
          {
              throw new Exception("There were errors during generated code compilation");
          }
          else
          {
              // Find the proxy type that was generated for the specified contract
              // (identified by a class that implements 
              // the contract and ICommunicationbject)
              Type clientProxyType = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().First(
                  t => t.IsClass &&
                     t.GetInterface(contractName) != null &&
                      t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommunicationObject).Name) != null);


              // Get the first service endpoint for the contract
              ServiceEndpoint se = endpointsForContracts[contractName].First();
              //se = endpointsForContracts[contractName].First();

              WSHttpBinding wsBinding = this.fillWsHttpBinding();                 
              string encodeValue = "MIIFazCCBFO****"; // here we should use the encoded certificate value generated by svcutil.exe.
              X509Certificate2Collection supportingCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
              supportingCertificates.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(encodeValue));
              X509Certificate2 primaryCertificate = supportingCertificates[0];
              supportingCertificates.RemoveAt(0);
              EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(primaryCertificate, supportingCertificates);
              EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(primaryCertificate);
              var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(mexAddress,  identity);

              se.Binding = wsBinding;
              se.Address = endpoint;

              // Create an instance of the proxy
              // Pass the endpoint's binding and address as parameters
              // to the ctor                  
              object instance = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(
                   clientProxyType.Name,
                 false,
                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
                     null,
                  new object[] { se.Binding, se.Address }, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

              var methodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName);
              var methodParams = methodInfo.GetParameters();
              int count = args.Count();
              object[] args2 = new object[count];
              int i = 0;
              foreach (var service1 in methodParams)
              {
                  args2[i] = Convert.ChangeType(args[i], Type.GetType("System." + service1.ParameterType.Name));
                  i += 1;
              }
              Object retVal = instance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName).Invoke(instance, args2);/*Getting Error that certificate not provided???*/
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          string error = ex.ToString();
          MessageBox.Show("Error Invoking Method: " + ex.Message);
      }
  ```

  private WSHttpBinding fillWsHttpBinding()
  {

  ```
      WSHttpBinding wsBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
      wsBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
      wsBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
      wsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
      wsBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 30);
      wsBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
      wsBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
      wsBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
      wsBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288L;
      wsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760L;
      wsBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
      wsBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      wsBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
      wsBinding.AllowCookies = false;

      wsBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
      wsBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192;
      wsBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10485760;
      wsBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384;

      wsBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
      wsBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
      wsBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = false;

      wsBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
      wsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
      wsBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
      wsBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "";

      wsBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
      wsBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
      wsBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;

      return wsBinding;
  }
  ```

Comment: Post the exception information... How are other people supposed to know what error you are getting if you do not include it in your question?

Comment: I apologize. Actually, i am getting exception while invoke instance:
Object retVal = instance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName).Invoke(instance, args2);
Please see exception below:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The client certificate is not provided. Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are setting the certificate on the `EndpointIdentity` causes it to be used to validate the *service's* identity. You haven't set the client's credentials using `instance.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(...)`. You'll have to get the ClientCredentials from the ClientBase<> using reflection. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

```
var credentialProperty = instance.GetType().GetProperty("ClientCredentials");
var credentials = (ClientCredentials)credentialProperty.GetValue(instance, null);
credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertficate(...);
```

You've also got two calls to `EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity`, ignoring the output of one of them.

Comment: Thanks, But problem is i am not getting option to set certificate in object named as instance in above code?

Comment: You'll need to use reflection to get the ClientCredentials property from "instance".  In fileWsHttpBinding() you shouldn't need to set Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType.

Comment: Yep i agree with you. I have already tried reflection to get the ClientCredentials property from "instance", but unable to setvalue to property. I am getting below exception:
System.ArgumentException: Property set method not found.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)

Comment: You shouldn't need to call SetValue(). I've updated my answer above.